# Unsupported media type "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryABC" when requesting to Django server

Tags: javascript, python, django, angular, typescript

I'm uploading a set of data (file, string, number, bool) to an Django api. The docs says `Note: the schema is not json it's multipart` so I made use of formData which is multipart. But when I upload this form I get this error

> "Unsupported media type "multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryABC" in request"

so I tried to add the content type multipart httpheader but this also resulted in an error:

> unsupported mediative "multipart" in request

I actually don't know where the error lies. Either in the api or in my front end code, so I'll add the essential parts of both down here:

Django:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    src = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False, editable=False, upload_to=utils.get_file_path,)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    when = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    lock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    des = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex='^[-_a-zA-Z0-9\.]+$',
                message='only 1 to 20 characters and only letters, numbers, point, minus and underscore are allowed',
            ),
        ])
```

view.py

```
  @swagger_auto_schema(request_body=doc_serializer.CreatePostDummy, responses={201: PostSerializer})
        def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            """permission required: authenticated. Note: the schema is not json it's multipart"""
            return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

doc_serializers.py

```
class CreatePostDummy(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(required=False, read_only=True, view_name='user-detail')
    src = serializers.CharField(required=True, help_text='Not Char but image upload field')
```

frontend

upload.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.categoryForm = new FormGroup({


      'lock': new FormControl(true),

      'des': new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.maxLength(25),
        Validators.minLength(1),
        Validators.required
      ])),

      'image': new FormControl(null),
      'when': new FormControl(null),
    });

}

apiSubmit() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('lock', this.categoryForm.get('lock').value);
  formData.append('des', this.categoryForm.get('des').value);
  formData.append('image', this.categoryForm.get('image').value);
  formData.append('when', this.categoryForm.get('when').value);


  this.http.post<any>(`{this.url}`, formData).subscribe(
    (res) => console.log(res),
    (err) => console.log(err)
  );
}
```

Comment: share the view please

Comment: @GeancarloMurillo Ive added if you need more, tell me.

Comment: I gather that you're using Django Rest Framework? It looks like this error is being raised: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/335054a5d36b352a58286b303b608b6bf48152f8/rest_framework/exceptions.py#L208. If so, the solution is probably to use a different parser: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser.

Comment: Yes its Django rest framework. Where in my code would I have to put the different parser?

Comment: @ColinRagnarök Did you read the section entitled “setting the parsers” in that link?

Comment: If you you are using django rest and passing through html form than try passing through raw using json it worked for me